# mysql issue inserting with mysql strict mode off

Tags: mysql, cpanel

I have strict mode off, but still getting the below error and it's really puzzling me, would greatly appreciate some help!

I am using mysql 5.6, on a cpanel/whm centos server

`` Warning: #1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column `articles`.`link_contributor_id` at row 1 ``

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "innodb_strict_mode"` = `off`

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "sql_mode"` = `ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

Comment: can you share your query.?

Comment: update articles set link_contributor_id = '', text = " some text "

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem what i did was go to the WHM account, go to :

```
WHM -> SQL Services -> Edit SQL Configuration
```

Once on this page find the field "**SQL MODE**" and Remove Strict Transport, this is the line that worked for me.

```
ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Maybe this will help someone else in the future.